# Earlier line breaks in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, tocloft

Is there an option in `tocloft` to decrease the maximum length of lines in the TOC? I'd like long section titles get a line break earlier, to increase the white space before the page numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{long section title that in the TOC wraps to the next line at a point too far}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know about `\section[A shorter section title]{Your insanely long section title}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break of the ToC entries depend on the `r`ight `marg`in. [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) allows you to change this (from the default `2.55em`) using `\cftsetrmarg`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetrmarg{7em}% Default is 2.55em
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{long section title that in the TOC wraps to the next line at a point too far}
\end{document}
```